# Set the columns' width of a row under multicolum row

Tags: tables

I want to make a table like this one:
[image]

I've using:
[image]

and got the table
[image]

Please help me to adjust the width of columns Y1, Y2, and Y3 equally. Many thanks!

Comment: Please post your code as code rather than an image. That way people can copy and paste it to work with it easily. You can format it as code by highlighting it and using the {} button or by indenting it all 4 spaces. Maybe the tabularx package is helpful here? That provides an X column which might do what you want. But I'm not sure and I can't modify your imaged code to test...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

When a multicolumn entry is wider than the columns it spans, the extra space is put into the last spanned column.

A way to avoid that is to define a new length that matches the length of the contents of the multicolumn cell

```
\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{Measured surface roughness $R_a$ ($\mu$m)}
```

and then use 3 columns which width is 1/3 of this length (`>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.333\mylength}`)

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{Measured surface roughness $R_a$ ($\mu$m)}

\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}*{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.333\mylength}}*{2}{c}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Factor} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Measured surface roughness $R_a$ ($\mu$m)} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Responses} \\
\cline{2-6}\cline{10-11}\noalign{\smallskip}
Trial No. & A & B & C & D & E & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Mean ($\mu$m) & $S/N$ ratios (dB) \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
1&1&1&1&1&1&0.30&0.33&0.37&0.333&9.5104\\
2&1&1&2&2&2&0.26&0.28&0.26&0.267&11.4752\\
3&1&1&3&3&3&0.35&0.33&0.32&0.333&9.5363\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is the use of `tabularx` where a macro for Y column is defined as `\newcolumntype{C}` having the X column property. So that X columns can adjust to fit the `\linewidth` set for the table.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent  % use this or wrap it in a table environment -- reminded by Mico, thanks.  
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*5{c}*3{C{1}}*2{c}}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Factor} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Measured surface roughness $R_a$ ($\mu$m)} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Responses} \\
\cline{2-6}\cline{10-11}\noalign{\smallskip}
Trial No. & A & B & C & D & E & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & Mean ($\mu$m) & $S/N$ ratios (dB) \\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
1&1&1&1&1&1&0.30&0.33&0.37&0.333&9.5104\\
2&1&1&2&2&2&0.26&0.28&0.26&0.267&11.4752\\
3&1&1&3&3&3&0.35&0.33&0.32&0.333&9.5363\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably insert `\noindent` before the start of the `tabularx` environment -- or encase it in a `table` environment.

Comment: You've left the dirty work to me... :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller -- Nay, I admire you work (which is a must to read) in this site.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer by @Jesse and, in particular, using the machinery of the `tabularx` package, I would suggest you also do the following:

- Rather than use `\noalign{\smallskip}` directives to get more vertical space around the table's horizontal lines, I would load the `booktabs` package and use its macros `\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`. These macros will automatically insert the proper amounts of vertical space. And, unlike the `cline` command, `\cmidrule` allows trimming on the left and right, allowing you to have adjoining lines that don't touch.
- For the numerical entries in the final two columns, it may make sense to align the numbers on their decimal points. I suggest you use the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) for this purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\addtocounter{table}{3} % just for this example
\begin{table}
\caption{Small ball-furnished surface roughness of OFC}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *5{c} *3{C} 
  *2{S[table-format=2.4]}}
\toprule
Trial No.\ & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Factor} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Measured surface roughness $R_a$ ($\mu$m)} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Responses} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}
 & A & B & C & D & E & Y1 & Y2 & Y3 & 
{Mean ($\mu$m)} & {$S/N$ ratios (dB)} \\
\midrule
1&1&1&1&1&1&0.30&0.33&0.37&0.333&9.5104\\
2&1&1&2&2&2&0.26&0.28&0.26&0.267&11.4752\\
3&1&1&3&3&3&0.35&0.33&0.32&0.333&9.5363\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```